# Regex for searching sections containing specific wording

Tags: regex

I don't get it.. What regex find me the following of:

```
Begin bla Important bla End Begin bla boring bla End Begin bla Important bla End
```

I want to find all occurences of `Begin ... Important ... End,` 
but not(!) `Begin ... Boring ... End`

With `(Begin.*?Important.*?End)` I always find two blocks:

1) `Begin bla Important bla End`

2) `Begin bla boring bla End Begin bla Important bla End`

What is the right regex line for my task?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because the second block also has a `Begin bla Important bla End` . What defines a block in your case? If it is between Begin and End, then second block satisfies.

Comment: [Or like this](https://regex101.com/r/mP55aT/1).

Comment: Yes, a block start with "Begin" and ends with "End". Thanks @wiktor-stribiżew. Can you do that explicitly with "Important" in case if there even more sections?

Comment: @linc .. your link doesn't work..